# How to count the different packet number in two text file

Tags: c++, c

I have two text files `in.text` and `out.text`. I will read them in to `unsigned char **`, in which each element of array stores a data with length is T=32 as bellow code

```
char *filename = "in.text";
FILE *stream;
int numPackets = 10;
int T = 32; // Length of each packets
unsigned char **PacketsIn;
fopen_s(&stream, filename, "rb");   
fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET);
for (int i = 0; i < numPackets; i++) {      
    fread(PacketsIn[i], 1, T, stream);      
}
fclose(stream);
```

In same manner way, I can obtain `PacketsOut` with above code

```
filename = "out.text";
FILE *streamout;
numPackets = 10;
T = 32; // Length of each packets
unsigned char **PacketsOut;
fopen_s(&streamout, filename, "rb");    
fseek(streamout, 0, SEEK_SET);
for (int i = 0; i < numPackets; i++) {      
    fread(PacketsOut[i], 1, T, streamout);      
}
fclose(streamout);
```

I want to count how many different packet in `PacketsIn` and `PacketOut` (Each of them has 10 packets, we will compare first packet in `PacketsIn` and first packet in `PacketsOut`. If they are different, then count increases 1). Could you help me to solve it

This is what I tried

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numPackets; i++) {      
    if (PacketsIn[i] != PacketsOut[i])
       count++; 
}
```

Comment: Which language? `C` or `C++`?

Comment: I am using both C/C++ in visual studio.

Comment: _`PacketsIn[i]!=PacketsOut[i]`_ This compares only two pointers, not the content they're pointing to. You need either `stdcmp()` or `memcmp()`.

Comment: Can you read your files without segfault ? You don't even allocate memory for your 2d arrays !

Comment: Do you want answers in `C` or `C++`?

Comment: I am welcome for both languare

Comment: It's important to know if c or c++: he answers using c++ containers+algorithm will be fundamentally different from memcmp based plain c

Comment: @Christophe: You are right. I did not allocate memory for PacketsOut and PacketsIn. Could you help me to allocate it

Comment: If numpackets and T are both const you could just declare unsigned char PacketXXX[numpackets][T]; if it has to be dynamic, i'd suggest vectors instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packets are arrays of bytes, you must allocate memory for these arrays, either as automatic storage, local to the function or from the heap with `malloc`.  Furthermore, you cannot compare arrays with `==` or `!=`, you need to use a function that performs byte by byte comparison.  `memcmp` declared in `<string.h>` does this and returns a non 0 value if the arrays differ.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <string.h>

int compare_packets(void) {
    FILE *stream;
    int numPackets = 10;
    int T = 32; // Length of each packet
    unsigned char PacketsIn[numPackets][T];
    unsigned char PacketsOut[numPackets][T];

    fopen_s(&stream, "in.text", "rb");   
    for (int i = 0; i < numPackets; i++) {      
        fread(PacketsIn[i], 1, T, stream);      
    }
    fclose(stream);

    fopen_s(&stream, "out.text", "rb");    
    for (int i = 0; i < numPackets; i++) {      
        fread(PacketsOut[i], 1, T, stream);      
    }
    fclose(stream);

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numPackets; i++) {      
        if (memcmp(PacketsIn[i], PacketsOut[i], T)
            count++; 
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When memcmp returns a nonzero value, this indicates difference between the two given strings:

```
#include <string.h>

if (memcmp(PacketsIn[i],PacketsOut[i],32)!=0)
   count++
```